# Re: Spoiler space?

Tags: discussion, markdown, spoilers

In this question here the OP asks for hints for a problem rather than a full proof.

[Proof of subfactorial formula $!n = n!- \sum_{i=1}^{n} {{n} \choose {i}} \quad!(n-i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14477)

Now, while I would like to respect that request, I also feel that questions on this site are not intended just for the OP's benefit.  This leads me to the question...

> **Question**: Is there any way to use some form of *spoiler space*, so that it's possible to post the answer for the other readers' benefit, but at the same time hiding it from those who do not want it?

My attempted "look at the previous version of this post" turned out a disaster.  I've seen people use rot13, but that seems like a lot of fuss (and clashes with the mathematics).

On some sites they use white text on white background for spoily material, which, when you select with the mouse, reveals the text.  Is that possible?

---

Testing:

> ! Spoiler Space
>
> ! More spoiler space

---

> Spoiler Space
>  More spoiler space

---

> What happens if I write a really long sentence.  Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

---

> Maybe it'll involve some maths like $E=mc^2$ or exclamation marks $n!=n \times (n-1)!$.

Comment: Excellent question, Douglas!

Comment: This is interesting, it might make a good compromise for answers to homework questions that are a bit spoily.

Comment: Man, now if only we could *preview* spoiler blocks, we'd be all set...

Comment: Hmm... since I don't have enough reputation to edit I don't know what are you guys doing for this? Any help?

Comment: @Deb: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/220fe78b-db82-463a-a55c-f1c35b908255/view-source)...

Answer (score 11):

Good idea.  I searched meta.stackoverflow.com to see if this had already come up, and I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396), showing that it was recently implemented. I'm going to try it:

> $$!n = n!- \sum_{i=1}^{n} {{n} \choose {i}} \quad!(n-i)$$

Comment: Hmmm... it works here, but I didn't manage to get it working over at the parent site (it just highlights the text and puts an ! at the start of the sentence).

Comment: Okay, worked it out... it doesn't like two >!'s separated by an empty line.

Comment: And thank you for finding this out, Jonas.  I will probably be trying it out myself.

Comment: This is awesome. Maybe we should be putting something about this in the FAQ. This certainly should help towards the problem of how to handle homework!

Comment: I hope we don't bump up too many old questions from our editing previous answers to have spoilers... ;P

Comment: What an odd implementation of the idea... With so much 2.0ishness couldn't they just put a button or something? Text appearing and disappearing because I'm moving the pointer from one side of my screen to another and the thing happens to be in the middle... Great!

Comment: @J.M.: I bumped one, mainly because I had already been tempted to post a spoiler after waiting a while to let the OP figure out the details.  This just gave me an excuse :)

Comment: I was itching to edit in a complete solution to one of my previous answers, but I didn't want to easily give the whole thing away to the OP. Now I'd better have a look at that answer again... XD

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sample bit of LaTeX contained in a spoiler block:

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$
>  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

This is the code I used to produce it:

```
  >! $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$  
  >! $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
```

However, when I moused over the spoiler block in the preview area while composing this post:

[image]

So, displayed equations don't appear displayed in the preview area, although they come out just fine in the final product.

Answer (score 5):

Some more testing:

1.

> *italicized text goes here*

2.

> **bold text goes here**

3.

> Let's try $\LaTeX$ *italicized text* **bold text** and [hyperlinks](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

4.

> $$\color{red}{\text{Does}}\;\color{green}{\text{colored}}\;\color{blue}\LaTeX\;\color{yellow}{\text{work?}}$$ But *black* **text** and $\LaTeX$ should still be obscured.

I'll edit this when I think of more stress tests.

Comment: >! But it doesn't work in comments.

Comment: @JM: $\color{white}{\text{spoiler}}$

Comment: @Kenny: Yeah, I know about that; I'm just demonstrating that the functionality doesn't work in comments. ;)

Answer (score 4):

What may be needed is a means by which an answer is visible to everyone except the OP.

Comment: Since OPs can trivially log out and view the question and its answers as a visitor, and since they can trivially have *two* accounts, going to such extremes is pretty pointless. We should never underestimate the amount of work people will do to  avoid work...

Comment: Perhaps the answer would only be visible to users (other than the OP) who also have a certain minimal reputation level?

Comment: Meanwhile, my actual view is that full solutions to homework questions are no problem and actually good for the site, as long as the quesions and answers are interesting. The only problematic issue I see with homework is that the problems might be boring for most users. I would enjoy seeing some very good homework problems!

Comment: The OP can always view the source (e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/a3136e19-5bd6-4d9c-b35c-53c4004e2f6a/view-source)

Answer (score 0):

I would very much prefer that we did *not* use this feature. It is simply too distracting.

I am really surprised that this has been deemed accetable UI!

Comment: I wasn't a fan of it either, but people love their spoilers... it came up on multiple sites with wildly different backgrounds, and got upvoted a lot.

Comment: @Jeff: while I can understand why some people would like having some kind of UI for this, did the *actual implemenation* get many votes? If so, well, this is just another example of the universal truth that design is best not be done by polling...